# In Kotlin How Can I Convert an Int? to an Int

Tags: java, nullable, kotlin

I'm using a `HashMap<Int, Int>` in Kotlin and when I `get` out of it the return type is `Int?`.

How can I convert the `Int?` to an `Int`?

So far I've tried using `Int?.toInt()`, but that seems to be returning an `Int?`.

I'm writing a Fibonacci function, and my code looks like:

```
val fibMemo : Map<Int, Int> = HashMap<Int,Int>()
fun fibN(n:Int) : Int {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1
    if (fibMemo.containsKey(n))
        // Error here: Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected
        return fibMemo.get(n)?.toInt()
    else {
        val newNum : Int = fibN(n-1) + fibN(n-2)
        fibMemo.put(n, newNum)
        return newNum
    }
}
```

Comment: There are newer answers that are current for Kotlin.

Comment: This question is now answered by the more current and complete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562

After that question has accepted answer and votes, this should be closed as duplicate of that.  In meta.stackexchange.com one recommended way to modernize questions and answers is to create a new one, and then close the old while adding a reference to the new.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The direct answer, use the [`!!` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) to assert that you trust a value is NOT null and therefore changing its type to the non null equivalent.  A simple sample showing the assertion allowing the conversion (which applies to any nullable type, not just `Int?`)

```
val nullableInt: Int? = 1
val nonNullableInt: Int = nullableInt!! // asserting and smart cast
```

Another way to convert a value is via a null check.  Not useful in your code above, but in other code (see [Checking for null in conditions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-keyword--in-conditions)):

```
val nullableInt: Int? = 1
if (nullableInt != null) {
   // allowed if nullableInt could not have changed since the null check
   val nonNullableInt: Int = nullableInt
}
```

This questions is also answered by the idiomatic treatment of nullability question: [In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562)

Answer (score 11):

In order to convert an `Int?` to an `Int` use the `sure()` method.

The offending line should look like:

```
return fibMemo.get(n).sure()
```

> Call to method `sure()` is Kotlin way (soon to be replaced by special language construct) to ensure non-nullability. As Java has not notation of nullable and non-nullable types we need to take some care on integration point. Please read amazing story of null-safety in Kotlin documentation.

[source](http://java.dzone.com/articles/kotlin-guice-example)

**Warning**: the above information doesn't hold anymore. `sure` has been replaced by `!!`. See: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/migrating-sure/

Comment: By the way, this example shows that even if map.contains(n) is true, in multithreaded environment, map.get(n) can result in null value.

Comment: Why not change the answer to be current and drop the `.sure()` answer entirely since it is completely wrong for current Kotlin.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a default value in null case:

`val int: Int
 val nullableInt: Int? = null
 int = nullableInt ?: 0`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to checking for the presence of the key, you will also need to ensure that the returned value is not `null` as `java.util.HashMap` allows `null` values.

You can do that by either surrounding your call to `get` with an explicit `null` check or by invoking `!!` on the returned value.

Your workaround to use `as Int` will be flagged as an unsafe cast warning by IDEA, and therefore is not advisable.

Comment: How can I use a map of `Int` then? I am always inserting non-nullable ints into the map, so they are guaranteed to be not-null.

Comment: Also, I'd love to contribute to the Euler project and perhaps augmenting some flog the std libs.

Comment: As you've probably figured out, the downside of relying on `sure()` is that you lose null safety at runtime. However, since you are certain that you are always mapping keys to non _null_ values, you should go ahead and use `sure()` regardless.

Comment: As for helping solve Project Euler (PE) problems, my understanding is that the PE site administrators strongly discourage collaboration and rather encourage people to individually explore the mathematical concepts behind each problem.

Comment: I'm not interested in the mathematical implications of the problems, (I've solved lost of them before)  I'm interested in creating a good reference for the language as well as contribute to its development.

Comment: Please replace sure with `!!` in your answer, since it is not part of Kotlin for years.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a null check

```
var a : Int? = 12
var b : Int      
b = a // error!
b = if(a != null) a else -1    //automatic typecast from Int? to Int
```

You can refer more about null-safe Type casts over here : [Null Safety - Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Answer (score 3):

You also can use [getOrPut](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-or-put.html) function to avoid contains/put in you code. See

```
val fibMemo = HashMap<Int, Int>()
fun fibN(n: Int): Int = when {
    n < 0 -> throw IllegalArgumentException("fib is not applicable to $n")
    n == 0, n == 1 -> 1
    else -> fibMemo.getOrPut(n) { fibN(n - 1) + fibN(n - 2) }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is ***you can't*** unless you emphatically state to the compiler that the `nullable int` can't and won't be `null` through the use of two exclamation marks or through the use of an `if statement`; because `int` is a `subtype` of `int?`

Here is an example.

```
val x:Int? = 1
val y: Int =2

x=y // No error
y=x // Error
y=x!! // No error
```