# In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them

Tags: nullable, kotlin, non-nullable

If I have a nullable type `Xyz?`, I want to reference it or convert it to a non-nullable type `Xyz`.  What is the idiomatic way of doing so in Kotlin?

For example, this code is in error:

```kotlin
val something: Xyz? = createPossiblyNullXyz()
something.foo() // Error: "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Xyz?"
```

But if I check null first it is allowed, why?

```kotlin
val something: Xyz? = createPossiblyNullXyz()
if (something != null) {
    something.foo() 
}
```

How do I change or treat a value as not `null` without requiring the `if` check, assuming I know for sure it is truly never `null`?  For example, here I am retrieving a value from a map that I can guarantee exists and the result of `get()` is not `null`.  But I have an error:

```kotlin
val map = mapOf("a" to 65,"b" to 66,"c" to 67)
val something = map.get("a")
something.toLong() // Error: "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Int?"
```

The method `get()` thinks it is possible that the item is missing and returns type `Int?`.  Therefore, what is the best way to force the type of the value to be not nullable?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin topics are present in SO.  Also to clarify some really old answers written for alphas of Kotlin that are not accurate for current-day Kotlin.*

Answer (score 336, accepted):

First, you should read all about [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#null-safety) in Kotlin which covers the cases thoroughly.

In Kotlin, you cannot access a nullable value without being sure it is not `null` ([Checking for null in conditions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-keyword--in-conditions)), or asserting that it is surely not `null` using the [`!!` sure operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator), accessing it with a [`?.` Safe Call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls), or lastly giving something that is possibly `null` a default value using the [`?:` Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).

**For your 1st case in your question** you have options depending on the intent of the code you would use one of these, and all are idiomatic but have different results:

```
val something: Xyz? = createPossiblyNullXyz()

// access it as non-null asserting that with a sure call
val result1 = something!!.foo()

// access it only if it is not null using safe operator, 
// returning null otherwise
val result2 = something?.foo()

// access it only if it is not null using safe operator, 
// otherwise a default value using the elvis operator
val result3 = something?.foo() ?: differentValue

// null check it with `if` expression and then use the value, 
// similar to result3 but for more complex cases harder to do in one expression
val result4 = if (something != null) {
                   something.foo() 
              } else { 
                   ...
                   differentValue 
              }

// null check it with `if` statement doing a different action
if (something != null) { 
    something.foo() 
} else { 
    someOtherAction() 
}
```

For the "Why does it work when null checked" read the background information below on [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

**For your 2nd case in your question** in the question with `Map`, if you as a developer are sure of the result never being `null`, use `!!` sure operator as an assertion:

```
val map = mapOf("a" to 65,"b" to 66,"c" to 67)
val something = map.get("a")!!
something.toLong() // now valid
```

or in another case, when the map COULD return a null but you can provide a default value, then `Map` itself has a [`getOrElse` method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-or-else.html):

```
val map = mapOf("a" to 65,"b" to 66,"c" to 67)
val something = map.getOrElse("z") { 0 } // provide default value in lambda
something.toLong() // now valid
```

---

## Background Information:

**Note:** *in the examples below I am using explicit types to make the behavior clear.  With type inference, normally the types can be omitted for local variables and private members.*

### More about the `!!` sure operator

The `!!` operator asserts that the value is not `null` or throws an NPE.  This should be used in cases where the developer is guaranteeing that the value will never be `null`.  Think of it as an assert followed by a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

```kotlin
val possibleXyz: Xyz? = ...
// assert it is not null, but if it is throw an exception:
val surelyXyz: Xyz = possibleXyz!! 
// same thing but access members after the assertion is made:
possibleXyz!!.foo()
```

*read more: [!! Sure Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator)*

---

### More about `null` Checking and Smart Casts

If you protect access to a nullable type with a `null` check, the compiler will [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) the value within the body of the statement to be non-nullable.  There are some complicated flows where this cannot happen, but for common cases works fine.

```kotlin
val possibleXyz: Xyz? = ...
if (possibleXyz != null) {
   // allowed to reference members:
   possiblyXyz.foo()
   // or also assign as non-nullable type:
   val surelyXyz: Xyz = possibleXyz
}
```

Or if you do a `is` check for a non-nullable type:

```kotlin
if (possibleXyz is Xyz) {
   // allowed to reference members:
   possiblyXyz.foo()
}
```

And the same for 'when' expressions that also safe cast:

```kotlin
when (possibleXyz) {
    null -> doSomething()
    else -> possibleXyz.foo()
}

// or

when (possibleXyz) {
    is Xyz -> possibleXyz.foo()
    is Alpha -> possibleXyz.dominate()
    is Fish -> possibleXyz.swim() 
}
```

Some things do not allow the `null` check to [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) for the later use of the variable.  The example above uses a local variable that in no way could have mutated in the flow of the application, whether `val` or `var` this variable had no opportunity to mutate into a `null`.  But, in other cases where the compiler cannot guarantee the flow analysis, this would be an error:

```kotlin
var nullableInt: Int? = ...

public fun foo() {
    if (nullableInt != null) {
        // Error: "Smart cast to 'kotlin.Int' is impossible, because 'nullableInt' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time"
        val nonNullableInt: Int = nullableInt
    }
}
```

The lifecycle of the variable `nullableInt` is not completely visible and may be assigned from other threads, the `null` check cannot be [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) into a non-nullable value. See the  "Safe Calls" topic below for a workaround.

Another case that cannot be trusted by a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) to not mutate is a `val` property on an object that has a custom getter.  In this case, the compiler has no visibility into what mutates the value and therefore you will get an error message:

```kotlin
class MyThing {
    val possibleXyz: Xyz? 
        get() { ... }
}

// now when referencing this class...

val thing = MyThing()
if (thing.possibleXyz != null) {
   // error: "Kotlin: Smart cast to 'kotlin.Int' is impossible, because 'p.x' is a property that has open or custom getter"
   thing.possiblyXyz.foo()
}
```

*read more: [Checking for null in conditions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-keyword--in-conditions)*

---

### More about the `?.` Safe Call operator

The safe call operator returns null if the value to the left is null, otherwise continues to evaluate the expression to the right.

```kotlin
val possibleXyz: Xyz? = makeMeSomethingButMaybeNullable()
// "answer" will be null if any step of the chain is null
val answer = possibleXyz?.foo()?.goo()?.boo()
```

Another example where you want to iterate a list but only if not `null` and not empty, again the safe call operator comes in handy:

```kotlin
val things: List? = makeMeAListOrDont()
things?.forEach {
    // this loops only if not null (due to safe call) nor empty (0 items loop 0 times):
}
```

In one of the examples above we had a case where we did an `if` check but have the chance another thread mutated the value and therefore no [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).  We can change this sample to use the safe call operator along with the `let` function to solve this:

```kotlin
var possibleXyz: Xyz? = 1

public fun foo() {
    possibleXyz?.let { value ->
        // only called if not null, and the value is captured by the lambda
        val surelyXyz: Xyz = value
    }
}
```

*read more: [Safe Calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)*

---

### More about the `?:` Elvis Operator

The Elvis operator allows you to provide an alternative value when an expression to the left of the operator is `null`:

```kotlin
val surelyXyz: Xyz = makeXyzOrNull() ?: DefaultXyz()
```

It has some creative uses as well, for example throw an exception when something is `null`:

```kotlin
val currentUser = session.user ?: throw Http401Error("Unauthorized")
```

or to return early from a function:

```kotlin
fun foo(key: String): Int {
   val startingCode: String = codes.findKey(key) ?: return 0
   // ...
   return endingValue
}
```

*read more: [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator)*

---

### Null Operators with Related Functions

Kotlin stdlib has a series of functions that work really nicely with the operators mentioned above.  For example:

```kotlin
// use ?.let() to change a not null value, and ?: to provide a default
val something = possibleNull?.let { it.transform() } ?: defaultSomething

// use ?.apply() to operate further on a value that is not null
possibleNull?.apply {
    func1()
    func2()
}

// use .takeIf or .takeUnless to turn a value null if it meets a predicate
val something = name.takeIf { it.isNotBlank() } ?: defaultName

val something = name.takeUnless { it.isBlank() } ?: defaultName
```

---

### Related Topics

In Kotlin, most applications try to avoid `null` values, but it isn't always possible.  And sometimes `null` makes perfect sense.  Some guidelines to think about:

- in some cases, it warrants different return types that include the status of the method call and the result if successful.  Libraries like [Result](https://github.com/kittinunf/Result/) give you a success or failure result type that can also branch your code.  And the Promises library for Kotlin called [Kovenant](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/) does the same in the form of promises.
- for collections as return types always return an empty collection instead of a `null`, unless you need a third state of "not present".  Kotlin has helper functions such as [`emptyList()` or `emptySet()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) to create these empty values.
- when using methods which return a nullable value for which you have a default or alternative, use the Elvis operator to provide a default value.  In the case of a `Map` use the [`getOrElse()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-or-else.html) which allows a default value to be generated instead of `Map` method `get()` which returns a nullable value.  Same for [`getOrPut()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-or-put.html)
- when overriding methods from Java where Kotlin isn't sure about the nullability of the Java code, you can always drop the `?` nullability from your override if you are sure what the signature and functionality should be.  Therefore your overridden method is more `null` safe.  Same for implementing Java interfaces in Kotlin, change the nullability to be what you know is valid.
- look at functions that can help already, such as for [`String?.isNullOrEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-char-sequence/is-null-or-empty.html) and [`String?.isNullOrBlank()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-char-sequence/is-null-or-blank.html) which can operate on a nullable value safely and do what you expect.  In fact, you can add your own extensions to fill in any gaps in the standard library.
- assertion functions like [`checkNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html) and [`requireNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html) in the standard library.
- helper functions like [`filterNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/filter-not-null.html) which remove nulls from collections, or [`listOfNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) for returning a zero or single item list from a possibly `null` value.
- there is a [Safe (nullable) cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) as well that allows a cast to non-nullable type return null if not possible. But I do not have a valid use case for this that isn't solved by the other methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is a hard act to follow, but here's one quick and easy way:

```
val something: Xyz = createPossiblyNullXyz() ?: throw RuntimeError("no it shouldn't be null")
something.foo()
```

If it really is never null, the exception won't happen, but if it ever is you'll see what went wrong.

Comment: val something: Xyz = createPossiblyNullXyz()!! will throw a NPE when createPossiblyNullXyz() returns null. It's simpler and follows conventions for dealing with a value you know isn't null

Comment: This pattern is still quite useful, especially for request validation. Yes, if it's not allowed to be null you could just assert !!, but you may want to throw a more explicit exception that your code can understand and format for you. HandledException(message = "Email is required", status = 400) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that now it exists [Konad](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad) library that addresses more complex situations for nullable composition. Here it follows an example usage:

```
val foo: Int? = 1
val bar: String? = "2"
val baz: Float? = 3.0f

fun useThem(x: Int, y: String, z: Float): Int = x + y.toInt() + z.toInt()

val result: Int? = ::useThem.curry() 
   .on(foo.maybe) 
   .on(bar.maybe) 
   .on(baz.maybe)
   .nullable
```

if you want to keep it nullable, or

```
val result: Result<Int> = ::useThem.curry() 
   .on(foo.ifNull("Foo should not be null")) 
   .on(bar.ifNull("Bar should not be null")) 
   .on(baz.ifNull("Baz should not be null"))
   .result
```

if you want to accumulate errors. See [maybe section](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad#maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer contains the complete detail, here I am adding the summary

### How to call functions on a variable of nullable type

```
val str: String? = "HELLO"

// 1. Safe call (?), makes sure you don't get NPE
val lowerCaseStr = str?.toLowerCase()   // same as str == null ? null : str.toLowerCase()

// 2. non-null asserted call (!!), only use if you are sure that value is non-null
val upperCaseStr = str!!.toUpperCase()  // same as str.toUpperCase() in java, NPE if str is null
```

### How to convert nullable type variable to non-nullable type

Given that you are 100% sure that nullable variable contains non-null value

```
// use non-null assertion, will cause NPE if str is null
val nonNullableStr = str!!      // type of nonNullableStr is String(non-nullable)
```

---

### Why safe(?) or non-null(!!) assertion not required inside null check if block

if the compiler can [guarantee](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) that the variable won't change between the check and the usage then it knows that variable can't possibly be null, so you can do

```
if(str != null){
   val upperCaseStr = str.toUpperCase()   // str can't possibly be null, no need of ? or !!
}
```