# What use is "?" in ArrayList<String?>

Tags: java, kotlin

Does it mean list item can be `String` or non `String`? I find the usage in following code:

```
class KotlinGreetingJoiner(val greeter: Greeter) {

    val names = ArrayList<String?>()

    fun addName(name: String?) {
        names.add(name)
    }

    fun getJoinedGreeting(): String {
        val joiner = Joiner.on(" and ").skipNulls()
        return "${greeter.getGreeting()} ${joiner.join(names)}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe we should mark this question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o

Answer (score 14):

It means the list elements can be either `String` or `null`. This is covered under [Null Safety](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) in the documentation.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562 for dealing with null values.  Also note that `filterNotNull()` method is available on Kotlin collections that let's you eliminate the `null` values if desired or convert to a list that is no longer capable of having nulls.