# How to use Kotlin's `with` expression for nullable types

Tags: kotlin, nullable, with-statement

The code below will not compile because the variable `myType` can be null. Is there a way of executing a `with` block for nullable types in Kotlin?

```
    val myType: MyType? = null
    with(myType) {
        aMethodThatBelongsToMyType()
        anotherMemberMethod()            
    }
```

Comment: how about wrapping it in `myType != null`? Kotlin smart casts should handle it.

Comment: Just a small remark: in Kotlin, `with` is not an operator but a function with two arguments of types `T` and `T.() -> R`, so its usage is the same to usage of any other function. See `with` documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can convert a nullable type to a non-nullable type with the suffix `!!`:

```
with(myType!!) {
    aMethodThatBelongsToMyType()
    anotherMemberMethod()            
}
```

If the value is indeed null, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, so this should generally be avoided.

A better way to do this is to make the execution of the code block dependent on the value being non-null by making a null-safe call and using the `apply` extension function instead of `with`:

```
myType?.apply {
    aMethodThatBelongsToMyType()
    anotherMemberMethod()            
}
```

Yet another option is to check if the value is non-null with an `if` statement. The compiler will insert a smart cast to a non-nullable type inside the if-block:

```
if (myType != null) {
    with(myType) {
        aMethodThatBelongsToMyType()
        anotherMemberMethod()            
    }
}
```

Comment: There are much more information about dealing with nulls in Kotlin, please add to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own `with` function that accepts nullables, then determines whether to actually run based on whether the object is null.

Like this:

```
fun <T, R> with(receiver: T?, block: T.() -> R): R? {
    return if(receiver == null) null else receiver.block()
}
```

Then you can call the code the way you wanted to in the example with no issues, and the result will equal `null` if what you pass in is `null`.

Or, if the code block should (and could) be run either way, even if `myType` is `null`, then you'd define it like this instead:

```
fun <T, R> with(receiver: T?, block: T?.() -> R): R {
    return receiver.block()
}
```

Comment: You could significantly improve the answer explaining how to do it (e.g. explain extension functions with nullable receiver).

Comment: Agreed, some sample code would definitely enrich this answer.