# How to compose nullables in Kotlin

Tags: nullable, kotlin

Let's imagine you have 2 fonctions returning nullable and you cant to compose this 2 functions :

```
fun giveInt(x: Int):Int? = x+1
fun giveInt2(x: Int):Int? = x+2
```

To achieve the composition, I wrote this functions :

```
fun all(x:Int):Int? {
  val y = giveInt(x)
  if (y != null) return giveInt2(y) else return null;
}

val four = all(1)
```

Is it possible to compose 2 nullable values to get another nullable without explicitly writing `if (y != null)` and `return null`?

In Scala I would just do something like :

```
def giveInt(x: Int):Option[Int] = Some(x+1)
def giveInt2(x: Int):Option[Int] = Some(x+2)
def all(x:Int): Option[Int] = giveInt(x).flatMap(giveInt2)
```

Should I use java Optional to achieve this or is it possible with `?` operator?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is heavily covered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to literally compose two functions (in the FP sense), then it is better to use function references for readability:

```
fun giveInt(x: Int):Int? = x+1
fun giveInt2(x: Int):Int? = x+2

fun all(x: Int): Int? = giveInt(x)?.let(::giveInt2)
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible with `safe call ?.` operator and `let` function combo like this:

```
fun giveInt(x: Int):Int? = x+1
fun giveInt2(x: Int):Int? = x+2

fun all(x: Int): Int? = giveInt(x)?.let { giveInt2(it) }
```

For more idioms like this, use [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html).

Comment: Making your methods extension methods would simplify the process tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

the answer of voddan is ok when you have only two nullables, but doesn't scale well on many nullables or in complicated use-case. For these situations there exist [Konad](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad) library that handles multiple nullables as follows:

```
val foo: Int? = 1
val bar: String? = "2"
val baz: Float? = 3.0f

fun useThem(x: Int, y: String, z: Float): Int = x + y.toInt() + z.toInt()

val result: Int? = ::useThem.curry() 
   .on(foo.maybe) 
   .on(bar.maybe) 
   .on(baz.maybe)
   .nullable
```

if you want to keep it nullable, or

```
val result: Result<Int> = ::useThem.curry() 
   .on(foo.ifNull("Foo should not be null")) 
   .on(bar.ifNull("Bar should not be null")) 
   .on(baz.ifNull("Baz should not be null"))
   .result
```

if you want to accumulate errors. See [maybe section](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad#maybe)