# How to pattern match optionals in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, control-flow

Is it possible to write something like this, or do we have to revert back to manual null checking in Kotlin?

```
val meaningOfLife : String? = null

when meaningOfLife {
    exists -> println(meaningOfLife)
    else   -> println("There's no meaning")
}
```

Comment: the `if` construct is more preferable for binary situations like this one. Has the exact same effect as `when` here

Comment: Why is it preferrable if it has the same effect? The advantage of `when` is that it has room to grow.

Comment: In case of nullability `when` has nothing to grow for. Using `when` as a glorified `if` is quite wasteful IMO

Comment: It's only wasteful if `when` desugars to something that uses more resources than a plain `if`. If not, then you have one less line and conditional expandability in contrast to `if`.

Comment: When I see `when`, I prepare myself to a multy-chose. So it would surprised  me to find only a bi-chose.

Comment: It is only a matter of taste. Fortunately Kotlin allows us to do what we think is necessary

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of possible ways is to match `null` first so that in `else` branch the `String?` is implicitly converted to `String`:

```
val meaningOfLife: String? = null

when (meaningOfLife) {
    null -> println("There's no meaning")
    else -> println(meaningOfLife.toUpperCase()) //non-nullable here
}
```

This is a special case of a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) performed by the compiler.

Similar effect can be achieved with `is String` and `else` branches -- `is String`-check is true when the value is not null.

For more idioms regarding null-safety please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34498563/2196460).

Comment: Making `is String` the first case achieves a similar effect.

Comment: @EPadronU, not completely: as seen from bytecode perspective, `is String` causes `instanceof` check, while the code in the answer doesn't, it only compares the reference with `null`.

Comment: Thank you. That's very useful to know. Fortunately, I said "similar" ;)

Comment: Unfortunately the smart cast only works if `meaningOfLife` is immutable. There's no way around `meaningOfLife!!.function()` when it's mutable, is it?

Comment: @TomTom, the compiler cannot guarantee null-safety in case of `var`, so there's indeed no other way but to create another local `val`. But when a variable is non-nullable and you only need smart cast for `var` you can write something like `myVar.let { when (it) { /*smart cast works here*/ } }`.

Answer (score 13):

You can accomplish that as follows:

```
val meaningOfLife: String? = null

when (meaningOfLife) {
  is String -> println(meaningOfLife)
  else -> println("There's no meaning")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the particular situation in the question has a way simple solution with the `?:` operator of default value:

```
println(meaningOfLife ?: "There's no meaning")
```

The example in the question is probably a simplified real situation, so a null check is how I would do it. IMHO `if` is a better way to go when you have a binary chose of control flow:

```
if(meaningOfLife != null)
    println(meaningOfLife)
else
    println("There's no meaning")
```

Takes exactly the same number of lines, BTW.

Comment: I understand the question was probably not about it, but I think this option should also be mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val meaningOfLife : String? = null    
meaningOfLife?.let { println(it) } ?: println("There's no meaning")
```

[let in stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)

Comment: OP wanted to know how to use pattern matching to do it. Anyways, I think your expression could be cleaned up to this: `println(meaningOfLife ?: "There is no meaning")`