# Is there any better way to access nullable property?

Tags: kotlin

What is the best way to convert **sound.id** property from nullable to nonnulable and pass it as param of play method?

```
class Sound() {
var id: Int? = null
}

val sound = Sound()
...
//smarcat imposible becouse 'sound.id' is mutable property that
//could have changed by this time
if(sound.id != null)
    soundPool.play(sound.id, 1F, 1F, 1, 0, 1F)

//smarcat imposible becouse 'sound.id' is mutable property that
//could have changed by this time
sound.id?.let {
    soundPool.play(sound.id, 1F, 1F, 1, 0, 1F)
}
```

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the argument provided by [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) which will be non-null:

```
sound.id?.let {
    soundPool.play(it, 1F, 1F, 1, 0, 1F)
}
```

or

```
sound.id?.let { id ->
    soundPool.play(id, 1F, 1F, 1, 0, 1F)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let{}` is the solution here.

Just write it like this:

```
sound.id?.let {
    soundPool.play(it, 1F, 1F, 1, 0, 1F)
}
```

--edit--

`it` is an argument here that is of type `Int` (not `Int?`) - thanks @mfulton26 for pointing that out

Comment: FYI: In this example, `it` is not a *receiver*. If it were then you would need to use `this` instead of `it`.