# Write in parcer nullable value in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcel

Backend returns nullable **Int?**
How should I write nullable value?

```
 date class Foo (var value: Int?){
   constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
     source.readInt()
   )

   override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
     dest.writeInt(value) // doesn't compile - writeInt expect no null value
   }
 }
```

Now I got solution:

```
dest.writeInt(value?: -1)
```

And then check to -1

or write Int like string and then use value of...

but I think it's ugly and wrong.

**RESOLVED! My answer:**

```
source.readValue(Int::class.java.classLoader) as Int?,
dest.writeValue(value)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `dest.writeInt(value!!)` work? As far as I remember Android doesn't  care if you pass a `null` value into Parcel.

Comment: !!- occur nullPointerexception and crash!

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @andrei_zaitcev `writeInt` takes an unboxed Java integer which is not nullable. You can't pass null to this method.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for misleading @Yvgen. My bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resolved by:

```
source.readValue(Int::class.java.classLoader) as Int?,
dest.writeValue(value)
```

Comment: You can use `source.readValue(null)` because integer is supported by the system class loader - same in all processes. See [`Parcel` source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java;l=2854;drc=master).

Answer (score 2):

This largely depends on what is the semantics of `null` as a value of your nullable property. It can mean:

- If `value` is null then it is absent and should not be written at all:

  ```
  value?.let { writeInt(it) }
  ```

  Of course, the `Parcel` receiver should be able to determine if it should read the value or not, this should be clear from the values written earlier.
- `value` is provided by some code, and it is an error if it is null at the point where it should be written:

  ```
  check(value != null) { "value should be not null at the point it's wriiten" }
  writeInt(value!!)
  ```

  Also, in this case, consider using [`lateinit var`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) instead of nullable property.
- Some default value should be used instead of `value`:

  ```
  writeInt(value ?: someDefaultValue())
  ```

  With `Parcel`, this does make sense, because otherwise, if the value is missing, you have to specify the fact somewhere else.
- ... (`null` can actually mean many things)

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o/34498563) shows many idiomatic ways of dealing with nullable values, and you might find some of them useful.

Comment: "If value is null then it is absent and should not be written at all" Yes, but we still need to know about this absence when unmarshalling so *something* has to be written.

Answer (score -1):

Use data keyword along with Parcelable,

```
@Parcelize
data class CallIssue(
                  var name : String? =null,
                  var status: String? = null ,
                  var mobile: String? = null,
                  var priority: Int = 0,
                  var natureOfWork: String? = null,
                  var department: String? = null,
                  var village: String? = null,
                  var time_reported: Date? = null,
                  var reporter: String? = null,
                  var assignee: String? = null,
                  var issue_id: String? = null,
                  var startDate: Date? = null,
                  var endDate: Date? = null,
                  var gender : String?= null,
                  var description: String? = null,
                  var commentList: List<String>? = null,
                  var expanded: Boolean = false) : Parcelable
```

If you are using @Parcelize then use "data" keyword otherwise all value are null after when you pass data from one activity to other activity.