# Errors when converting Java to Kotlin code

Tags: kotlin

So this is my Java code that works

```java
if (currentForecastJava.getCurrentObservation().getTempF() >= 60) {
    mCurrentWeatherBox.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.weather_warm));
    mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.weather_warm));
} else {
    mCurrentWeatherBox.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.weather_cool));
    mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.weather_cool));
}
```

What I am trying to do is write this in Kotlin(know AS has the converter but does not change anything)

```
if (currentObservationKotlin.tempF.compareTo() >=)

    currentWeatherBox.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.weather_warm))
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.weather_warm))

else currentWeatherBox.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.weather_cool))
     toolbar.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.weather_cool))
```

I know I need a value in the compareTo() and after but I am not really sure what to place as I want to compare TempF to 60 as I want the color to change based on the TempF value from data class. I do not have another object to compare it to.

I can write this in Java and it works with the rest of the Kotlin code but trying to see if Kotlin can make the Java if/else similar and quicker to write.

Comment: Why not just `currentObservationKotlin.tempF >= 60`?

Comment: I can use currentObservationKotlin.tempF!! >= 60 and everything compiles and works as expected but not sure why I need to put !!. Still trying to learn the null stuff with Kotlin.

Comment: When I do as suggested above, I get an error on the >= operator. I states that "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public final operator fun compareTo(other: Double): Int defined in kotlin.Double".I can use currentObservationKotlin.tempF!! >= 60 and everything compiles and works as expected but not sure why I need to put !!. Still trying to learn the null stuff with Kotlin.

Comment: Looks like getCurrentObservation() is declared to return a nullable type. You can't compare a value of a nullable type with anything, because it would produce an NPE if the value was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java and Kotlin version would be almost the same.  Start with the Java code and drop the semicolons `;` and then anything that COULD be nullable needs to be handled with either `null` checks or you asserting that they will never be null with `!!`, or using another `null` operator.  You do not show enough code (i.e. the method signature coming into this code, or the declaration of the used variables) to tell you exactly what needs to change.

*For handling `null` values see: [In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562)*

You might end up with warnings around calling a setter method as `something.setXyz(value)` instead of assigning it as a property `something.xyz = value` and the IDE will help you fix those or you can live with the warning.

*For more about interoperability with JavaBean properties see: [Java Interop: Getters and Setters](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters)*

So with all of that in mind, your final code (with a little more cleaning) might appear something like:

```
val currentTemp = currentForecastJava.getCurrentObservation()?.getTempF() ?: -1 
// or change -1 to whatever default you want if there is no observation
if (currentTemp >= 60) {
    val warmColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.weather_warm)
    mCurrentWeatherBox.backgroundColor = warmColor
    mToolbar.backgroundColor = warmColor
} else {
    val coolColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.weather_cool)
    mCurrentWeatherBox.backgroundColor = coolColor
    mToolbar.backgroundColor = coolColor
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, will look into both links. I see your using the Elvis operator also. I was trying to do that first, but wasn't able to create the code correctly. Is it always better to create another val/car with Kotlin then just using var currentTemp: Double = currentObservationKotlin?.tempF!! and just setting that to a TextView?

Comment: I only created other variables to make the code clearer what steps were doing what.  They are optional.