# How do I run a block of code if a nullable type is null?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In Kotlin, I can run code if an object is not null like this:

```
data?.let {
    // execute this block if not null
}
```

But how can I execute a block of code if the object is null?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use a normal `if`:

```
if (data == null) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: And what if data is mutable in a concurrent environment?

Comment: @AlwynSchoeman Your current function is continuing synchronously and doing whatever you wanted to do in the case `data` was null at the moment you checked it. If you need to prevent it from being set to some other value while this if block is running, you must `synchronize` on something whenever working with the property.

Comment: @Tenfour04 threads...

Answer (score 188):

You can use the [**elvis** operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) and evaluate another block of code with `run { ... }`:

```
data?.let {
    // execute this block if not null
} ?: run {
    // execute this block if null
}
```

But this seems not to be quite as readable as a simple `if`-`else` statement.

Also, you might find this Q&A useful:

- [In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o)

Comment: Be careful, if `let {}` returns `null`, both blocks would run!

Comment: `apply {}` would be safer.

Comment: @SillyFreak yes it is, i have a logic problem because of this

Comment: This has the danger that if by mistake the let {} block returns null the run {} block will be executed.

Answer (score 54):

Here's a concise syntax using the Elvis operator. Recall the Elvis operator only executes the right side if the left side evaluates to null.

```
data ?: doSomething()
```

Comment: The best example of KISS

Comment: This is really cool.

Comment: Kotlin does not seem to like doSomething) to be a block, like data ?: { doSomething(); return 0 } - it writes to me "Return is not allowed here"

Answer (score 30):

You can create an infix function like this:

```
infix fun Any?.ifNull(block: () -> Unit) { 
  if (this == null) block()
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
data ifNull {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: This would run **ifNull { }** only if data is null?

Comment: I like this when all you really want to do is test for null and do something then exit.

Comment: Be careful with this approach, because ```something.ifNull{}``` will work, whilst ```something?.ifNull{}``` is not gonnna be called!

Answer (score 16):

You can use below code

```
myNullable?.let {

} ?: { 
    // do something
}()
```

also you can omit `fun()`

```
myNullable?.let {

} ?: fun() { 
    // do something
}()
```

or you can call `invoke()` instead of `()`

```
myNullable?.let {

} ?: fun() { 
    // do something
}.invoke()
```

Note that returning value differs like below.

```
val res0 = myNullable?.let {
} ?: () {

}()
val res1 = myNullable?.let {
} ?: fun() {
    "result"    
}()
val res2 = myNullable?.let {
} ?: () {
    "result"    
}()


println("res0:$res0")
println("res1:$res1")
println("res2:$res2")
```

RESULT:

```
res0:kotlin.Unit // () {} with empty
res1:kotlin.Unit // fun() {}
res2:result      // () {} with return
```

Comment: `let` will apply the function with `myNullable` as object even if `myNullable` is null.

Comment: @ssasi Could you describe more specific your case? I wrote the answer two years ago, this is needed to be updated if there're something error.

Answer (score 2):

**let** can apply on null as well, regardless if the object is null or not:

```
data.let {d->
    if (d != null){
        // execute this block if data is not null
    } else {
        // for data is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you do that with the following language constructs:

```
data?.also {
    // execute this block if not null
} ?: run {
    // execute this block if null
}
```

be careful with

```
data?.let {
    // execute this block if not null
    // but careful, returning null accidenatlly will execute run {} as well.
    null
} ?: run {
    // execute this block if null
}
```

The **let** block might return **null** variable accidentally and the **run** block will execute as well.

If you don't like the constructs `also` and `run` you can change the name to something like below:

```kotlin
inline fun <T> T?.ifNotNull(block: (T) -> Unit): T? {
    if (this != null) {
        block(this)
    }
    return this
}

inline fun <T> T.elseIfNull(block: () -> Unit) {
    if (this == null) { block() }
}
```

and use like this:

```kotlin
class A
var a1: A? = null
var a2: A? = A()
 
a1.ifNotNull {
    println("a1 is Not Null: $it")
}.elseIfNull {
    println("Is null do something else")           
}

a2.ifNotNull {
    println("a2 is Not Null $it")
}.elseIfNull {
    println("Is null do something else")           
}
```

Above guarantee the second block won't execute if the top one returns null accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution,

```
fun runIfNull(any: Any?, block: () -> Unit) {
        if (any == null) block()
}
```

Which you use as:

```
runIfNull(any) { // it will run; }
```

It has an advantage comparing to @Dmitry Ryadnenko's answer,
where one might be confused and might use it incorrectly.
There you have a function

```
infix fun Any?.ifNull(block: () -> Unit) { 
  if (this == null) block()
}
```

And in case you use it on a null object in the way:

```
nullObject?.ifNull { // THIS WILL NOT BE CALLED }
nullObject.ifNull { // this will be called }
```

The block is not going to be executed.
Please note the mistakenly added question mark '?'

Answer (score 0):

Following answer is simpler version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502281/2987755) answer.
Function returns valid list if chain calls are successful
else
returns `emptyList()`

```
class A(var b: B? = null)
class B(var c: C? = null)
class C(var d: D? = null)
class D(var list: List<String>?)

//1. Note ? in A?.<functionName>
fun A?.isNull(): List<String> {
    if(this == null) { // 2. access object using this keyword
        return emptyList<String>()
    }
    return this.b?.c?.d?.list ?: emptyList<String>()
}

fun main() {
    //1. Empty A object
    var a: A? = A()
    println(a.isNull()) //[]
    
    //2. Null A object
    a = null
    println(a.isNull())  //[]
    
    //3. All Valid chaining parameters
    val d = D(listOf("d"))
    val c = C(d)
    var b : B? = B(c)
    a = A(b)
    println(a.isNull())  //[d]
    
    //4. Invalid chain parameter
    b = null
    a = A(b)
    println(a.isNull()) //[]
}
```