# Not nullable value required to call 'component1()' function of destructuring declaration initializer

Tags: kotlin, nullable, destructuring

Is it possible to make the following code to compile in Kotlin?

```
val variable: String? = "string"

val (a, b) = variable?.run {
    1 to 2
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler does not allow destructuring because the expression on the right-hand side is typed as a nullable `Pair<Int, Int>?`, and it's unclear what values `a` and `b` should get in case `variable` is null.

To solve this, you need to get a not-null expression after `=`.

There's a lot of different ways to deal with nullable values and produce a not-null value from a nullable one, see: [In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o)

For example, if you want to provide fallback values for `a` and `b`, then use the `?:` operator as follows:

```
val (a, b) = variable?.run {
    1 to 2
} ?: (0 to 0)
```

An alternative, for example, would be to check `variable` for null first:

```
val (a, b) = checkNotNull(variable) { "variable should never be null" }.run {
    1 to 2
}
```

Comment: I think `a` and `b` should be both null if `variable` is null or I'm missing something? `variable` is allowed to be null and the fallback values should be null in that case.

Comment: I added `?: (null to null)` at the end and it worked, but I believe it could be done automatically.

Comment: You actually need `null as Int? to null as Int?` if you want `a` and `b` to be `Int?` rather than `Any?`.

Comment: ?: (null to null) does not work for me in latest kotlin, same exception.

Answer (score 6):

Null doesn't have any destructuring declarations. If you want a value of null to destructure like it's a pair of nulls, you could add these extensions:

```
operator fun <T> Pair<T, *>?.component1() = this?.component1()
operator fun <T> Pair<*, T>?.component2() = this?.component2()
```

Otherwise, as the other answer shows, you need to provide a default using the Elvis operator.

It's not automatic because it doesn't know what you want.  Depending on what you're doing with it, `0 to 0` may be most appropriate, or maybe `-1 to -1` or `0 to null` or `null to null`.

Comment: There is the elvis operator if we would like to define a default value other than null. I think it would be reasonable to return `null to null`.

Comment: You could open an issue on YouTrack to suggest it. It's not a part of the stdlib. I suppose if there were a default, it would have to be `null to null` so it would work for any types.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, what do you want to do if your variable is null? If you want to throw an exception, go with `require` or `check` as @hotkey suggested.

However I have the case where I just want to return if the value is null. So I wrote myself a little helper function that allows for this:

```
private inline fun <T> T?.exitIfNull(exitBlock: () -> Nothing): T {
    if (this == null)
        exitBlock()
    else
        return this
}
```

You can call this function as follows:

```
val (a, b) = variable?.run {
    1 to 2
}.exitIfNull {
    return
}
```

A nice little use of the `Nothing` keyword in Kotlin that I personally find quite fascinating