# handle null or return value from jpa repository method

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

How do I grab whatever value comes back from the JpaRepository findByIdOrNull method and return?

```
@Service
class IDLookupService(
    private val iDRepo: IdRepo,
) : Logging {
    fun lookupIdValue(email: String): IdModel? {
        var response = IdModel()
        runCatching { 
            Failures.failsafeRun {
                iDRepo.findByIdOrNull(email)
            }
        }.onFailure {
            throw IDLookupException("Exception while searching DB for IDValue")
        }
        return response
    }
}

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class IdModel(
    val IdValue: String
    )
```

it could be a value that should go directly into the IdModel I setup or null. I seem to be having issues with the !! not-null assertion operator whenever I try to assign variables within the failsafe run

Comment: first of all, `IdModel()` this shouldn't work, since you have a data class with a primary constructor that you are ignoring. Secondly, what do you want to happen when the value is null? Considering that the IdModel expects a non-null `String`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o)

Comment: What you probably want is to do `val idValue: String = iDRepo.findByIdOrNull(email) ?: return null` (note the type of `idValue` is `String`, not `String?`), then you can create and return your model `return IdModel(idValue)`. See the example in the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator. You can also throw the exception if you want, `val idValue: String = iDRepo.findByIdOrNull(email) ?: throw IDLookupException(...)`, and then the return type of your function is non-nullable, `fun lookupIdValue(...): IdModel`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (please use try catch as per your need, but basic code hopefully will look like this) -

```
@Service
    class IDLookupService(
        private val iDRepo: IdRepo,
    ) : Logging {
        fun lookupIdValue(email: String): IdModel? {
            runCatching { 
               Failures.failsafeRun {
                 return iDRepo.findByIdOrNull(email)?.run {
                   IdModel(this)
                 } ?: null
               }
            }.onFailure {
               throw IDLookupException("Exception while searching DB for IDValue")
            }
        }
```

Comment: for some reason I can't return from the failsaferun method it's telling me

Type mismatch.
Required:
Unit